# Parsing HTML tags out of script tag with HtmlCleaner

Tags: java, html, scala, htmlcleaner

I'm using HtmlCleaner to parse html documents and have run into a little problem:

On the [htmlcleaner properties guide](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/parameters.php) it says that if I set the useCdata flag to false that it will search for html within script and style tags. OK so here I go:

```
scala> val cleanerProps = new CleanerProperties()
cleanerProps: org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties = org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties@203e9b48

scala> cleanerProps.setUseCdataForScriptAndStyle(false)

scala> val clnr = new HtmlCleaner(cleanerProps)
clnr: org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner = org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner@4a5800a9

scala> val test = """<script language="javascript">
     | document.write('<h1>Obviously a heading</h1>')
     | </script>"""
test: java.lang.String =
<script language="javascript">
document.write('<h1>Obviously a heading</h1>')
</script>

scala> clnr.clean(test).getElementsByName("h1", true)
res61: Array[org.htmlcleaner.TagNode] = Array()
```

Shouldn't htmlcleaner have found an h1? To make matters more confusing, the following work fine:

```
scala> val test2 = """document.write('<h1>Obviously a heading</h1>')"""
test2: java.lang.String =
"document.write('<h1>Obviously a heading</h1>')"
scala> clnr.clean(test2).getElementsByName("h1", true)
res62: Array[org.htmlcleaner.TagNode] = Array(h1)
```

or

```
scala> clnr.clean(test.replaceAllLiterally("script","style")).getElementsByName("h1", true)
res65: Array[org.htmlcleaner.TagNode] = Array(h1)
```

???

Comment: why is this tagged javascript? Have removed tag